Unexpected behavior of msmtp with subprocess
I want to send emails from my python code calling msmtp using subprocess. Some of the emails are longish (maybe a few kB's, but not insanely long). The following code works fine with maybe 10 lines of email, but with any more than that then the email is sent Ok with correct subject but no body text at all.
p = subprocess.Popen(('msmtp', '-t'), stdin=open("email_file.txt"), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

Where email_file.txt contains the To/From/Subject and Body text in the format that msmtp expects. I know the file format is fine and msmtp is happy working because the plain linux command:
cat email_file.txt | msmtp -t

works just fine with longish email body text.
I have also tried piping the email text file line by line using:
p = subprocess.Popen(('msmtp', '-t'), stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in email_file_handle.readlines():
    p.stdin.write(line.encode('utf-8'))
p.stdin.close()

but this has the exact same result

Just some ideas if you are stuck... consider providing a minimal (11 line?)  email_file.txt that causes problems. Consider capturing stderr too. Consider writing a dummy msmtp in bash that copies its stdin to a temporary file you can inspect.

Ooops... really sorry everyone- totally my bad. I have been chopping my "email_file.txt" into ever finer pieces to better find the root cause, and have determined that my issue is related to msmtp after all.
I have a timestamp on most lines of my email, and I think the issue occurs when the first line of the file includes the timestamp (eg: 13:24:56). I have lost the will to go on chopping right now but I think its something to do with the colons? I will have to figure this out though, so if this question hasn't been deleted for being terrible, then I will answer my own Q in a couple of days.

Everything before the first blank line is message headers, of the form Name: value. So 13:24:56 looks like a header named 13, with value 24:56. You should probably change that to something like X-Timestamp: 13:24:56. Or leave it out entirely, since email automatically gets a Date: header with the current timestamp.

Thanks Barmar. Happy to accept this as the answer if you'd like the points. Points mean prizes after all... : )
